# Android GCM Push notifications to multiple users from a database

Tags: php, android, mysql, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to incorporate GCM push notifs to my app. I was reading a tutorial but unfortunately it uses REST api and slim framework and I don't have an idea on those and it will be time consuming for me to study about those. What I am thinking right now is to just SIMPLY assign each user in the database with a gcm registration id and send them a notification. But the problem is I don't know how to get gcm registration id in the simplest way. I have less knowledge when it comes to PHP or server side. Can someone help me or just give me a link tutorial using simple implementations? I would really appreciate it.

By the way, the purpose of my push notif goes like this: On a specific period of time, let's say on a specific date, there will be a list of app users that are qualified for a contest. Those users should receive a notification on their phone once they are connected to the internet.

Comment: do you want to send notification through php or java app?? also you have to get Registration id of android phone using the same or do you have that ids??

Comment: @ELITE php or server side should be the one initiating to send notifications to android phone. if possible i wanted it to be automatic. for registration ids, i dont have those yet.

Comment: You have to get registration id using android app. And for sending notification you have to trigger the code like on button click of html or else

Comment: With respect, if you can't find a tutorial that tells you what you need to do, you might find the work required to implement that in a working app/backend beyond you. FWIW, I use GCM through AWS and the first 3 parts of their docs are generic IIRC http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-push-gcm.html

Comment: Seems like you need to get a basic GCM application working then you can apply that to your specific situation. Have a look at the getting started guide here: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start

Comment: [Send Push Notification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36506934/failed-to-send-push-notification/36507747#36507747)